# STM32 HAL_UART_Receive_IT doesn't get called for size argument of 2 or more

Tags: stm32

I am trying to use STM32 HAL function HAL_UART_Receive_IT with more than 1 element but it fails to be called, while it works without any issue with size of 1.

Please correct me if I am wrong, but in the code below there is part for the size:

```
    huart->pRxBuffPtr = pData;
    huart->RxXferSize = Size;
    huart->RxXferCount = Size;
```

Isn't it wrong, because if both things are size that means you cannot have 1 byte data and 10 bytes of count (elements)?

Is this bug or something in the HAL ? Or....?

Full code for the function is:

```
/**
  * @brief  Receives an amount of data in non blocking mode.
  * @note   When UART parity is not enabled (PCE = 0), and Word Length is configured to 9 bits (M1-M0 = 01),
  *         the received data is handled as a set of u16. In this case, Size must indicate the number
  *         of u16 available through pData.
  * @param  huart Pointer to a UART_HandleTypeDef structure that contains
  *               the configuration information for the specified UART module.
  * @param  pData Pointer to data buffer (u8 or u16 data elements).
  * @param  Size  Amount of data elements (u8 or u16) to be received.
  * @retval HAL status
  */
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_UART_Receive_IT(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size)
{
  /* Check that a Rx process is not already ongoing */
  if (huart->RxState == HAL_UART_STATE_READY)
  {
    if ((pData == NULL) || (Size == 0U))
    {
      return HAL_ERROR;
    }

    /* Process Locked */
    __HAL_LOCK(huart);

    huart->pRxBuffPtr = pData;
    huart->RxXferSize = Size;
    huart->RxXferCount = Size;

    huart->ErrorCode = HAL_UART_ERROR_NONE;
    huart->RxState = HAL_UART_STATE_BUSY_RX;

    /* Process Unlocked */
    __HAL_UNLOCK(huart);

    /* Enable the UART Parity Error Interrupt */
    __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(huart, UART_IT_PE);

    /* Enable the UART Error Interrupt: (Frame error, noise error, overrun error) */
    __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(huart, UART_IT_ERR);

    /* Enable the UART Data Register not empty Interrupt */
    __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(huart, UART_IT_RXNE);

    return HAL_OK;
  }
  else
  {
    return HAL_BUSY;
  }
}
```

My code is:

```
#define GPS_Rx_buffer_size  10
uint8_t GPS_Rx_buffer[GPS_Rx_buffer_size];


HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart3,GPS_Rx_buffer,GPS_Rx_buffer_size);
```

Comment: How do you use the HAL? Have you looked at the RX interrupt implementation? To me the API comments say you must give the size of data elements you want to receive and they can be 1 byte elements or 2 byte elements based on USART settings, and your buffer must have enough room for that count of elements (e.g. 10 bytes for 5 elements of 16 bits). The next thing is, post your code which shows the buffer declaration and how you call the HAL function, and how you initialize the USART. Most likely you need 1 byte elements.

Comment: Tnx for replying, I wanted to get 10 elements of size 1 byte into 10 element (10 byte) buffer.

Comment: Also sentence "Amount of data elements (u8 or u16) to be received." is absolutely wrong in that case, because that can be calculated and user  wouldn't have to give that information at all. Also, what sense does it make to have RxXferSize  and RxXferCount and then give them same value? No sense at all.

Comment: Take a look at the code for your version of the HAL library - does it even *use* `huart->RxXferSize` anywhere? The one I'm looking at (for STM32F4) does not. So the fact that it's setting both `RxXferSize` and `RxXferCount` is in all likelihood unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Most will soon realize that, whatever the debateable tradeoffs of the the rest of the STM32 HAL, the UART interrupt receive is particularly awkward and that it is far more effective to simply write one's own UART receive interrupt handler and infrastructure as this can in most cases be an order of magnitude simpler while better fitting typical actual needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When characters are received, the (HAL-defined) `UART_Receive_IT()` is called, where `pRxBuffPtr` is incremented and `RxXferCount` is decremented. `RxXferSize` doesn't appear to be used. The I2C part of the library uses the same pattern, where `XferSize` is the *total* size to transmit and `XferCount` is limited to the *batch size* the hardware can handle, a potentially smaller number than `XferSize`. (This is not documented; I deduced it from source code.) UART might follow the same convention even though `RxXferSize` isn't needed in this case.

Note that if `huart->Init.WordLength == UART_WORDLENGTH_9B`, HAL typecasts to `(uint16_t*) huart->pRxBuffPtr` which requires you to align the target buffer on 2 bytes (another undocumented HAL quirk).

To debug your problem, set a debugger breakpoint in `UART_Receive_IT()` and make sure you know the incoming UART data, for example by monitoring the traffic with a PC terminal program and a cheap UART-to-USB converter.

One thing to look out for is correct setup of the pins in `HAL_UART_MspInit()` in the generated file `*_hal_msp.c`. Also, the relevant subsystem clocks must be activated and interrupts be enabled. Also double-check the settings for UART parity, stop bits, speed and flow control. Naturally, you need to wait for `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback()` as brhans pointed out.

*Usage tips:* Note that waiting for a specific number of bytes is risky; you should implement your own timeout to handle corrupted or missing data instead of hanging the program. The interrupt-based calls avoid the MCU busy-looping but can miss some characters if UART speed is high and the MCU has other concurrent tasks, as the interrupt handler must be called for every character without buffering. DMA will not miss characters but also takes additional logics to get to work well, and DMA is a limited resource.

I'm personally not impressed by the HAL and find myself gradually replacing the functionality with my own higher-level API that I intend to open-source.

Comment: With all that said, if the code you posted is your complete code, you definitely need to follow brhans' suggestions before looking further.

Comment: `buffer on 2 bytes (another undocumented HAL quirk)` do you expect HAL magically to save 9 bits in  8 bits?  Nothing to document here. It is obvious

Comment: It's reasonable for HAL to use two bytes. My complaint is that the memory alignment requirement is not documented.

Comment: The alignment is needed only on the M0 cores. M3 and newer will not require address to be aligned for this kind of store instructions.

Comment: @AndersPetersson - Hi, I have removed the question which was included in your answer. The whole Stack Exchange approach is that questions & answers are separate. If you want to ask about that topic, then please ask it as a separate question. However note there is a risk that the question you tried to ask *might* be deemed to be too broad. IIRC, there have been previous questions about STM32 HAL alternatives, HAL vs. LL, HAL vs. SPL etc. I recommend you research those previous questions first, if you haven't already. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the code you've posted, you don't know how to use the HAL UART library in interrupt mode correctly, and I strongly suggest you *r*efer back to *t*he *f*ine *m*anual.

You call to `HAL_UART_Receive_IT` does not receive any bytes *and it's not supposed to*.
All `HAL_UART_Receive_IT` does it to set up the receive operation and then immediately return.

Once the HAL UART Interrupt handler has finished receiving all the data you asked for in the `HAL_UART_Receive_IT` call, it makes a call to `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` to tell you that it's done.

`HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` is a function that *you* are supposed to implement in your code - the reason your project currently even builds without you having implemented that function is that the HAL library includes a default empty `weak HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` function.

Since the HAL interrupt code does not use `huart->RxXferSize`, it's probably intended to be used in your implementation of `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` so that it knows how many bytes of data it's being given.

Comment: Judging from your answer it seems you have missed the whole point.